# Conversion into matrix equation

Tags: calculus, optimization, vector-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to optimize a sum of the form:
$$
(\sum_{i} a_i k_i + \sum_{i,j}b_{i}\cdot b_j^{T} c_{i,j} +K)^2,
$$
where the $b_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of *a non-zero* $3\times 3$ matrix $b$, the $a_i$ are the components of a vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the $c_{i,j}$, $k_i$ and $K$ are non-zero scalars in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\|-\|_2^2$ is the square of the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My question is how do I convert the preceding equation into matrix form and find the vector $a$ and matrix $b$ optimizing it?

I'm quite new to Matrix calculus, so I'm sorry if this question is silly.

Comment: You are applying the Euclidean norm to a scalar, is that intended ?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same notation for scalars and vectors.

Comment: If "optimize" means "minimize", then pick $a_1 = -K/k_1$ and all other $a_i = 0$. Let the $b_i$ be anything. Then the entire expression is the square of the middle term, because the first and last terms cancel. But the middle term can be mae arbitrarily small by mutiplying each $b_i$ by a constant $s$, which will multiply the term by $s^2$, and hence the expression by $s^4$. So the infimum of possible values is certainly $0$. This problem needs more thought from the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

Well....if any one of the $k_i$ ... say $k_1$, is nonzero, then you can let all the $b_i$ be zero, pick $a_1 = -K/k_1$, and you get a norm of 0, which is pretty much minimal.

If you're hoping for maximal, then if any one of the $c_{ii}$, say $c_{1,1}$, is positive, you pick $b_1 = \alpha e_1$ and $b_2 = b_3 = 0$, and pick $a_i = 0$ for all $i$. THen by increasing $\alpha$, you can make the target value arbitrarily large.

From these two observations, I have to suspect that you've phrased the question wrong, but perhaps not.

Comment: Sorry the $b_i$ cannot *all* be 0.

Comment: The expression under the norm has $12$ free parameters, so there are many many ways to make it zero.

Comment: Ah...well, when you figure out what problem you actually want to solve, write it clearly and I'll give it another shot. Chameleon problems are the death of me. (You might also want to note Yves's answer; I was just being specific because sometimes that's more helpful than generalities.)